# MONGODB - cast type of every object in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB Collection where some documents have arrays of objects. One of the fields of this objects is `timestamp`.

The problem is that historically some of `timestamp` values are Strings (e.g. '2018-02-25T13:33:56.675000') or Date and some of them are Double (e.g. 1528108521726.26).

I have to convert all of them to Double.

I've built the query to get all the documents with the problematic type:

```
db.getCollection('Cases').find({sent_messages: {$elemMatch:{timestamp: {$type:[2, 9]}}}})
```

And I also know how to convert Date-string to double using JS:

```
new Date("2018-02-18T06:39:20.797Z").getTime()
> 1518935960797
```

But I can't build the proper query to perform the update.

Here is an example of such a document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6c88f656532aab00050dc023"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-18T03:43:18.986Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-18T06:39:20.798Z"),
    "sent_messages" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-18T06:39:20.797Z"),
            "text" : "Hey",
            "sender" : "me"
        }
    ],
    "status" : 1
}
```

After the update it should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6c88f656532aab00050dc023"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-18T03:43:18.986Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-18T06:39:20.798Z"),
    "sent_messages" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : 1518935960797.00,
            "text" : "Hey",
            "sender" : "me"
        }
    ],
    "status" : 1
}
```

Comment: what did you try as query update

Comment: You cannot do it in a single query. Iterate all matching documents and bulk.update them from application.

Comment: @AlexBlex It is possible to update in a single query with a `foreach`. Perhaps @Alexander, you can take inspiration from this answer here to find a solution for your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423151/4473762

Comment: Dear @RobertUdah, mongo shell is an interactive application. `foreach` is a javascript function available there. It iterates over the cursor clientside and issues 1 update request per document in the example you referred to. It is not a single request, even tho you can write it in a single line.

Comment: Dear @AlexBlex, Okay so the example I provided uses a javascript `foreach` but my point still stands. You can perform the operation with a single query by using `updateMany` or the `aggregate` function

Comment: @RobertUdah, sorry mate, no cigar again. `aggregate` is read-only and `update` requires constant values to set, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345. Really appreciate your enthusiasm tho. Beer on me if you prove me wrong.

Comment: @AlexBlex I'll look into this in more detail tomorrow as i'm pretty sure is possible with the `$out` operand in the aggregation function: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176172/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-robert-udah).

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you are trying to fetch the record first.

```
db.getCollection('Cases').find({sent_messages: {$elemMatch:{timestamp: {$type:[2, 9]}}}})
```

Then convert date in JS:

```
new Date("2018-02-18T06:39:20.797Z").getTime()
```

And then this is an update query:

```
db.getCollection('Cases').updateOne({_id:ObjectId("6c88f656532aab00050dc023")}, { $set: { "sent_messages.$.timestamp" : "218392712937.0" }})
```

And if you want to update all records then you should write some `forEach` mechanism. I think you have already this implemented.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: What if I have thousands of documents to fix? I can't do these steps manually.

Comment: Yes, then must we need to use `forEach` as you mentioned in your answer. This helps me too as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just do it with JS code that can be run in mongo console:

```
db.getCollection('Cases').find({sent_messages: {$elemMatch:{timestamp: {$type:[2, 9]}}}}).forEach(function(doc) {
  print('=================');
  print(JSON.stringify(doc));
  doc.sent_messages.forEach(function(msg){
    var dbl = new Date(msg.timestamp).getTime();
    print(dbl);
    msg.timestamp = dbl;
      });
   print(JSON.stringify(doc))
   db.Cases.save(doc);
} )
```

Thanks all for your help!